# Pygame windows freezes when I try to shut it off

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to open and close a pygame tab, but whenever I hit close it just freezes, and I am forced to force quit it from activity monitor. I work on a Mac.

So far I've tried a system exit, 'closing the pygame screen' script, and a file dedicated to closing pygame. (os.system("pkill Python")), and a handful of other things. All have not worked, therfore I am receptive to any advice.

```
 import subprocess
 import os
 import pygame

 pygame.init()

 running = 1

 W = 500
 H = 500

 screen = pygame.display.set_mode((W,H))

 while running == 1:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = 0
```

That is what I have now. I do not expect that to work, I am just waiting to come across a solution that will help me properly shut down the pygame tab.

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code and error message

Comment: instead of `1`, `0` you can use `True`, `False` and it will be more readable. And then you can even use `while running:`

Comment: did you try `pygame.quit()` - you should see this in every tutorial.

Comment: did you run it in terminal/console ? maybe it will show some information - ie. some Python's error message or system crash message.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `pygame.display.quit()` at the end of the application. See `pygame.display.quit`:

> This will shut down the entire display module. This means any active displays will be closed. This will also be handled automatically when the program exits.